# React Router - Making a breadcrumbs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to make a `Breadcrumbs` component with the help of `react-router-dom` and I've got a few questions

Say I'm given a route that looks like this:

```
breadcrumbRoutes: [
    {
      path: '/devicePolicies',
      exact: true,
      name: "Device Policies",
      main: () => <h2>Device Policies View</h2>
    },
    {
      path: '/devicePolicies/controlPanel',
      exact: true,
      name: "Control Panel",
      main: () => <h2>Control Panel View</h2>
    },
    {
      path: '/devicePolicies/controlPanel/settings',
      exact: true,
      name: "Settings",
      main: () => <h2>Settings View</h2>
    }
  ]
```

Currently, my `Breadcrumbs` component will render it to look like this `Device Policies/Control Panel/Settings`. However, it isn't correctly rendering the right component associated with the most recent path `/devicePolicies/controlPanel/settings`.  For example, instead of the rendering the `settings` component, it renders the `Home` component.

Breadcrumbs.js

```
Class Breadcrumbs extend Component

insertBreadcrumbs() {
var routes = this.props.routes;

    return (
      <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
          <ul className="breadcrumb">
            { this.insertListElement(routes) }
          </ul>
          {routes.map((route) => (
             <Route
                  key={route.path}
                  path={route.path}
                  exact={route.exact}
                  component={route.main}
             />
          ))}
     </div>
    );
}
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
              { this.insertBreadcrumbs() }
        </Router>
    );
}
```

App.js

```
<Breadcrumbs 
        name="breadcrumbRoutes"
        routes={this.state.breadcrumbRoutes}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
 />
```

How can I make the loaded view always be the last component of my path? In this example, I want to load the component of `settings`

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am a little confused about your implementation. Can we see more code?

Comment: @mattdevio Yes, I've added some more of my code. Hopefully this will make my question more clear

Comment: @Tim what is the function insertListElement doing? Can we see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what my problem was. Turns out, I was testing the behavior incorrectly. I was attempting to force my router to set the location to `settings` instead of making a `Link` that has `to="devicePolicies/controlPanel/settings`. By inserting that `Link`, I was able to *correctly* set my router location to `settings` which then correctly renders the respective component. Thank you all for your input!